# Randomly render one of the modules in a given position

Tags: module, templates, front-end, gantry, positions

I have several modules for a given position, but I only want to display one of them (selected randomly) on the front-end in a Gantry template.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you will need to duplicate and hack the position particle in core Gantry to do this. I did something similar some time ago displaying a different module depending on the time of day.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Module Helper documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Helper.ModuleHelper.html).

> `getModules()`:  **Get modules by position**
>
> getModules(string $position) : array static
> since 1.5
>
> Arguments
> $position string The position of the module
>
> Response array
> An array of module objects

and

> `renderModule()`: **Render the module.**
>
> renderModule(object $module, array $attribs = array()) : string
> static
> since 1.5
>
> Arguments
> $module objectA module object.
> $attribs array An array of attributes for the module (probably from the XML).
>
> Response string
> The HTML content of the module output.

This means that after declaring `use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;`, you can simply:

1. Fetch all of the modules at your designated position as an array.
2. Randomly select a single module object from the array of objects using [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).
3. Display/Echo the rendered module content.

Code:

```
$position = 'position-2';
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules($position);
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modules[array_rand($modules)]);
```

This is effectively an extension of [FFrewin's answer from 2014](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3761/12352).

---

In your template, write the jdoc placeholder.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" />
```

A short list of relevant pages to reference:

- [Joomla Documentation: Jdoc statements](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements)
- [Balbooa tutorial: How to Add New Module Position in Joomla?](https://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/177-how-to-add-module-position-in-joomla)
- [OSTraining thread: Templates, Modules, and JDOC statements](https://www.ostraining.com/joomla-support/5519-templates-modules-and-jdoc-statements/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is good information. However, I am using a Gantry template,  and I can't find where to put the codes.

Comment: @shenkwen I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're after a less code heavy way of doing it, you could use a mix of Regular Labs Modules anywhere and Regular Labs Articles Anywhere.

- Create your modules, and assign them all to a new position called "Random"
- Create a category called Random Modules
- Create articles for each of the modules using Module plugin syntax
- https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere/tutorial#how-to-use-it-syntax
- Create one more module that is assigned to the position you want the random modules to appear
- Use Articles Anywhere (note Pro edition needed for ordering) to make the module load a random article
- `{articles category="Random Modules" ordering="random" limit="1"}[title][fulltext]{/articles}`